# Returning a class that implements a variant interface

Tags: c#, generics, casting, covariance, contravariance

**Background:**

I have three Silverlight Pages, that implement my interface:

```
interface IPageWithData<in T> where T : Entity
{
    void SetData(T obj);
}

public class APage : Page, IPageWithData<AItem> { /* Implementation */ }
public class BPage : Page, IPageWithData<BItem> { /* Implementation */ }
public class CPage : Page, IPageWithData<CItem> { /* Implementation */ }

// AItem, BItem and CItem are (EF) Entities (they are derived from Entity class).
```

Then I use a custom manager that returns a page that relates to the treeview node given as a parameter:

```
private static class PageContainerHelper
{
    public static IPageWithData<Entity> SetPage(RadTreeViewItem selectedNode)
    {
        APageRTVI aNode = selectedNode as APageRTVI;
        BPageRTVI bNode = selectedNode as BPageRTVI;
        CPageRTVI cNode = selectedNode as CPageRTVI;

        if (aNode != null)
        {
            if (APage == null)
                APage = new APage();

            APage.SetData(aNode.aItem);
            return APage; // ERROR HERE
        }

        /*
            ... the same for BPageRTVI and CPageRTVI
        */
    }

    public static APage APage { get; set; }
    public static BPage BPage { get; set; }
    public static CPage CPage { get; set; }
}
```

**Problem:**

I seem to be understanding co/contravariance the wrong way.
The `SetPage()` method doesn't allow me to return `APage`:

> Cannot implicitly convert type **'MyProject.Views.Pages.APage'** to **'MyProject.Views.Pages.IPageWithData'**. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

`APage` implements `IPageWithData<T>` (albeit `T` is of a more derived type). Why does this require a explicit conversion? And would an explicit conversion even work here?

So basically, there are two things I need. One is that when `SetPage` is returning a page, it can use a page that implements `IPageWithData` of a type that is more derived than `Entity`. And the other thing I need is for the `IPageWithData<T>.SetData` method to be able to receive arguments that are of a type more derived than a `T`, that is `Entity`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider what you can do with `IPageWithData<Entity>`. You can do:

```
IPageWithData<Entity> pageWithData = PageContainerHelper.SetPage(...);
BItem item = new BItem();
pageWithData.SetData(item);
```

Now the *implementation* is an `APage` - what would you want it to be able to do with a `BItem`? I suspect you don't want that.

In other words, the compiler is doing exactly what it should - it's protecting you from sending the wrong kind of data to a page which can't handle it. Quite how you want to *fix* this, I don't really know - I suspect you want `SetPage` to be generic too:

```
public static IPageWithData<T> SetPage<T>(RadTreeViewItem selectedNode)
    where T : Entity
```

but it's not clear to me what that does to your implementation.